# How can I manage Drupal blog's posts?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I want to create a blog using Drupal 7 (because the customer told me that). The problem is, when the blog has too many posts, it's hard to manage these entries. Is there anyone know a plugin or a module that can help me manage blog's posts like Wordpress ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can try https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views and built the content page View how you want it to make it more manageable.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look on it